# Autofac + Prism + RequestNavigate shows error

Tags: wpf, prism, autofac

I'm trying to do a sample app with Autofac + Prism

```
class AppBootstrapper : Prism.Autofac.AutofacBootstrapper
{
    protected override void ConfigureContainerBuilder(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        base.ConfigureContainerBuilder(builder);

        builder.RegisterType<FirstView>();
    } 
}
```

Later on I navigate to the view

```
   regionManager.RequestNavigate("MyRegion", new Uri("FirstView", UriKind.Relative), (r) =>
   {
        Debug.WriteLine(r);
   });
```

But I am getting error saying that `FirstView` was not registered.

I know that with **Unity** the fix is to call:

```
container.RegisterType(typeof(Object), typeof(T), typeof(T).FullName);
```

What is the solution for Autofac?

Answer (score 1):

`builder.RegisterTypeForNavigation<FirstView>();`

See also [Prism RequestNavigate to new view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39024136/prism-requestnavigate-to-new-view)

Comment: Please add a description of how this solves the users question. Also, please read [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: This DOES provide the answer to the question.  The question was "what is the solution" and the solution was provided.