# Prism RequestNavigate to new view

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I am using `WPF Prism 6` with `autofac` and having issues navigating between views. What I have is a view that I only want to keep alive till I leave it, and the next time I navigate to it, I want to create a new version of this view.

On load, I regist an `IModule` that has the following code

```
_regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.MainRegion, 
                                      typeof(DxfDisplay.Views.DxfDisplay));
```

This registers my view and the system works on initial load, I implement the `INavigationAware` and `IRegionMemberLifetime` interfaces on the view model and have `public bool KeepAlive => false;` implementing the `IRegionMemberLifetime` so that my view is disposed when I am done.

When I navigate away from this view everything is fine, but when I attempt to navigate to navigate to the view using

```
_regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.MainRegion, 
                               new Uri("DxfDisplay", UriKind.Relative), parameters);
```

The view is not opened and a view model constructor is not called. To make the navigation work correctly, I need to register with view with the region again. Or if I change the KeepAlive to `true` I can navigate back to the original view, but I cannot generate a new view if `INavigationAware.IsNavigationTarget` returns false.

My question is how do I register the view with the region manager in such a way that when I call `_regionManager.RequestNavigate`, it will create a new instance of the view and display it. I feel like I am missing something simple and just overlooking it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_builder.RegisterTypeForNavigation<DxfDisplay.Views.DxfDisplay>();`

Comment: Thanks, never looked in the extension method namespace. I knew it had to be easy.

Answer (score 0):

In Prism 7, this is now called `RegisterForNavigation<T>()` and exists on the `IContainerRegistry` interface.

For example, in your module:

```
public class MyModule : IModule
{
    public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<MyView>();
    }
}
```